# MacOS-Big Sur VirtualBox Error the virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)

Tags: virtualbox, big-sur

This happens after updating into the MacOS Bug sur. And then trying to start the VirtualBox VMs,
Tried so far and no luck with below options,

1. Un-installed and re-installed the VirtualBox
2. Created completely new VM and tried
3. Re-installed `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16`

Anyone else came a cross with the same issue? any clue to resolve this would really appreciated.

This the the complete Error message

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine New Ubuntu.

The virtual machine 'New Ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Running `brew install virtualbox` from the terminal did the job for me, and  “allow oracle” in “Security & Privacy”

Comment: `brew install virtualbox` corrected the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[This](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=98763&sid=7541dfcace7a86fdb5bc8a281296ad94&start=75#p488555) worked for me

```
sudo su
csrutil clear
reboot
```

- Then uninstall (from the official uninstaller) and re-install VirtualBox
- If prompted, go to System Preferences - Privacy - General and accept the extensions
- Reboot

Comment: I had to do this again after updating Big Sur to 11.5. But I did not have to uninstall VirtualBox though. Thanks for this guide.

Comment: This also worked for me but instead of becoming root I just used:
`sudo csrutil clear` and then rebooted the machine + the reinstalling vbox

Comment: Hit me out of the blue after doing the 11.5.2 update. Thanks for the guide. (I also note that their installer now specifically says you have to reboot after install on Big Sur.)

Comment: This did not help me, unfortunately.

Comment: I'll add to my previous comment that I was dumb, and forgot I was on my M1 mac, where VirtualBox should not even work at all.

Comment: @Dronir Thanks!! Needs to be highlighted more: [VIRTUALBOX DOES NOT WORK ON NEW M1 MACS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422565/can-i-run-virtualbox-on-new-m1-macbook-air)

Comment: this one still works in the 2022. For me was enough just `sudo csrutil clear` and reboot

Answer (score 2):

I was reluctant to install using Homebrew rather than an official package, but it did resolve the problem for me. This command:

```
brew install --cask virtualbox
```

Installed a later version of Virtualbox (7.0.6) than any available on the Virtualbox website (6.1.40), and the new version worked on Mac OSX Ventura, while 6.1.40 did not (even after reinstalling and Allowing the kernel extension).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670176/virtualbox-error-kernel-driver-not-installedrc-1908#comment119766775_56758118 and https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19795.

Answer (score 0):

I received an error like this when trying to open a VM from the VirtualBox UI. (This was my first time installing VirtualBox or any VM.) I was able to run the VM from the commandline using:

`VirtualBoxVM --startvm <VM ID or unique name>`